# Отображение информации на HTML-сервере в Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Возник вопрос с началом изучения Node.js.
Хочу отобразить на странице заголовок и ссылку, но при добавлении заголовка ссылки пропадают.

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url === '/') {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'});
        //res.end('<h1>Корневая страница</h1>');
        res.end('<a href="/about">Ссылка на страницу /about</a>');
    } else if (req.url === '/about') {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'});
        //res.end('<h1>Страница about</h1>');
        res.end('<a href="/">Ссылка на страницу /</a>');
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'});
        res.end('<h1>Ошибка! Страница 404...</h1>');    
    }
});

const port = 3000;

server.listen(port);
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь вызывать end два раза подряд, что ли? Ну вроде из названия должно быть очевидно, что его можно вызывать ровно один раз `res.end('<h1>Корневая страница</h1><a href="/about">Ссылка на страницу /about</a>');`

Comment: а как тогда добавить еще и другой текст?

Comment: Все, разобрался: res.write('<h1>Корневая страница</h1>')